# when i run the playbook through putty to start httpd service am getting following error

Tags: apache

[ec2-user@tower1 ~]$ systemctl status httpd.service -l
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-10-28 12:13:49 UTC; 5min ago
Docs: man:httpd(8)
man:apachectl(8)
Process: 12139 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 12137 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 12137 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 28 12:13:49 tower1.12c2.internal httpd[12137]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Oct 28 12:13:49 tower1.12c2.internal httpd[12137]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Oct 28 12:13:49 tower1.12c2.internal httpd[12137]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Oct 28 12:13:49 tower1.12c2.internal httpd[12137]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Oct 28 12:13:49 tower1.12c2.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 28 12:13:49 tower1.12c2.internal kill[12139]: kill: cannot find process ""
Oct 28 12:13:49 tower1.12c2.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 28 12:13:49 tower1.12c2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 28 12:13:49 tower1.12c2.internal systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Oct 28 12:13:49 tower1.12c2.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.

Comment: also when i run the following command getting below result                                                
 ss -tlnp|grep -w 80
LISTEN     0      128          *:80                       *:*
LISTEN     0      128       [::]:80                    [::]:*

Comment: I guess there is another instance running. Check it with ```ps aux |grep httpd```. If there you see any processes, try to stop or kill it and restart the service again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.